# Switch between different Wasm runtimes in case of a bugs

Tags: runtime, wasm

Since the Wasm runtime is stored on-chain under consensus rules, if a bug is discovered, what is the procedure to switch to a different Wasm runtime? What if the bug affects the block production? Does it require to use the native runtime?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Fork-less

If the chain could produce blocks.

Set a new WASM through the runtime upgrade.

#### Hard fork

If the chain could produce blocks in native.

Use `--native`, and contact other validators to switch to `--native` (otherwise, your finalization will stall, then the chain bricked). Make a runtime upgrade and let all validators switch back to WASM mode. After this, I think you might need to mark some blocks as bad/fork blocks. Otherwise the new node can not finish the sync.

*I'm not sure about this, I haven't tried this before.*

#### Hard spoon

If you have tried all the ways and the chain could not produce blocks.

Export the chain state and start a new chain base on those exported data.

Comment: From what I understand, in the case of a runtime bug, on-chain governance does not fully apply, since the bug might affect the actual on-chain governance.
To me, it seems like the on-chain governance relies on the assumption that runtime logic is bug-free, but practically there are no guarantees. Am I missing something?

Comment: One more thing, here is a quote: `The deprecation of the native runtime will now be pursued with a much higher priority. Using the Wasm compiler Wasmtime already brings us to a performance level that is almost the same as using the native runtime, so we don’t really need the native optimization anymore. Especially with all the potential downsides.` What happens when the native runtime gets deprecated since it is one of the ways for resolving runtime bugs?

Comment: Just thinking conceptually, why not have 2 runtimes stored on-chain, the current and the previous one, in the case of a bug with the current runtime it can potentially fall back to the previous working one.